# netbeans 9 - svn support broken on macOs?

Tags: macos, svn, netbeans, netbeans-9

## The backdrop story

On macOs I have always depended on svnKit for SVN support in netbeans, as it just works out of the box even without svn installed. However as of Netbeans 9, svnKit support is broken with no intention to fix - see [NETBEANS-1302](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-1302):

> ... svnkit integration has been disabled, because some parts of it are
>   under licenses that are not allowed in an ASF project ...

So I need to fallback to installed CLI versions.

## My Problem

However after installing SVN (subversion.apache.org), I still get the dialog box with "SVN Command Failed" asking me to install or point to an already installed version.

I have it installed two different ways, the apple developer command line tools (svn 1.10.0), and through brew (svn 1.10.2).

I point netbeans to either `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` - but it fails to pick up the already installed svn cli.

Anything I am doing wrong? It must be working because I am referred to it by others? Or maybe only broken on macOs?

Note: this question is **not** about SvnKit support being broken: It is known that SvnKit is broken, and there is no intent to fix. So any question about SvnKit support in Netbeans 9 is right now pointless. The question is about integration with a true SVN client - I am not able to get that to work either on macOS.

Comment: Same here on Archlinux. NetBeans 9 is a *catastrophe*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the SVN version. Netbeans 9 does not support it (see [NETBEANS-771](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-771)...)
There is a patch of `org-netbeans-modules-subversion.jar` in that thread that supposedly fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the new org-netbeans-modules-subversion.jar provided in NETBEANS-771 but it made no difference on my Mac.

Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 9.0 (Build incubator-netbeans-release-334-on-20180708)
Java: 1.8.0_191; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.191-b12
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_191-b12
System: Mac OS X version 10.14.1 running on x86_64; UTF-8; en_US (nb)
svn --version
svn, version 1.10.0 (r1827917)
   compiled Sep 25 2018, 18:25:22 on x86_64-apple-darwin17.0.0

Comment: Make sure that this finding is logged in the JIRA